# angular js access variable in a service but same app

Tags: angularjs

How can I access a property of a controller in a service?

In my case it is an array, which I want to change in my service.

My controller:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $interval, externalDataService, AnalyzeService) {
    $scope.myArray = [];
    var size = 10;

    var analyze = function () {
       if($scope.myArray .length > size) {
          AnalyzeService.doSomething();
       }
    };

    var analyzeData = function () {
        externalDataService.getData().then(function (data) {
            $scope.faceReaderData.push(data);
            analyze();
         });
     };

    $interval(analyzeData , 2000);
});
```

My service:

```
myApp.service('AnalyzeService', function () {
    this.doSomething = function () {
        //here i want array access
    }
});
```

Comment: You can just pass the array into your service function as a parameter.

Comment: In my case I want make changes in the array, Like delete the first 10 Objects. If I pass the array into the service as a parameter i have to return it and set it as new array. And that´s what i dont want to

Comment: Why do you not want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to do that, as it would make your service depend on your controller, which is very undesireable. Instead, add the array as a parameter to your `doSomething`:

```
//Appending 1,2,3 to the given array
function doSomething(someArray) {
    return someArray.concat(['1', '2', '3']);
}
```

This way, your service does not depend on your controller at all, seperating your business logic from your controller.